# In Pug Interpolation, what's the real difference between using buffered code and using #{..}?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

As stated in the [docs](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) for interpolation:

> ```
> - var title = "On Dogs: Man's Best Friend";
> - var author = "enlore";
> - var theGreat = "<span>escape!</span>";
>
> h1= title
> p Written with love by #{author}
> p This will be safe: #{theGreat}
> ```
>
> `title` follows the basic pattern for evaluating a template local, **but** the code in between `#{` and `}` is evaluated, escaped, and the result buffered into the output of the template being rendered.
>
> This can be any valid Javascript expression, so you can do whatever feels good.

However, the buffered code in  `h1= title`  is still "evaluated, escaped, buffered...",  and "supports the full range of JavaScript expressions" as stated [here](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html).

So what is the difference? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

From [*Buffered Code* section in the docs](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#buffered-code):

> Buffered code starts with `=`. It evaluates the JavaScript expression and outputs the result. For security, buffered code is first HTML escaped.

From [*String Interpolation, Escaped* section in the docs](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-escaped):

> The code in between `#{` and `}` is evaluated, escaped, and the result buffered into the output of the template being rendered.
>
> This can be any valid Javascript expression, so you can do whatever feels good.

So, they both:

1. evaluate a JavaScript expression,
2. escape it,
3. output it / buffer it into the output.

I.e. they both do the same things. Which one to use then? My gut says:

- Use buffered code if the whole line is a JavaScript expression.
- Use string interpolation if only a part of a line is a JavaScript expression.

Example:

```
// Normal JS variables
- const name = 'John'
- const greeting = `Hello ${name}!`

// Buffered code
p= greeting                 // 1
p= 'Hello ' + name + '!'    // 2
p= `Hello ${name}!`         // 3

// Interpolation
p Hello #{name}!            // 4
p #{greeting}               // 5
p #{'Hello ' + name + '!'}  // 6
p #{`Hello ${name}!`}       // 7

// Output in all cases:
<p>Hello John!</p>
```

Notice that numbers 3 and 7 use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Not to be confused with Pug's string interpolation (numbers 4–7).

In my opinion:

- Numbers 1, 3 and 4 are the best options.
- Number 2 is OK, but using a template literal would be nicer (number 3).
- Numbers 5–7 are valid, but maybe a bit unnecessary – the lines don't contain anything else than the JS expressions inside the `#{` and `}`, so you might as well use buffered code for clarity. (But you might prefer them, and that's fine. This is a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: ok nice explanation, but it's the "but" in the docs (in" but the code between #{ and } ...") that made me confused. It seems like  they want to enhance a difference between using buffered code and string Interpolation. But, as we can see they're doing the same thing...

Comment: Hmm, I see. That might also be just an imperfect choice of words. You could try asking on Pug's GitHub repo by opening an issue. Remember to report back here if you do ask and get an answer. :-)